# Tensorflow Loss for Non-Independent Classes

Tags: tensorflow

I am using a Tensorflow network for classification between classes that are similar to their neighboring classes, i.e. not independent. For example, let's say we want to predict among 10 classes but the predictions are not merely "correct" or "incorrect." Instead, if the correct class is 7 and network predicts 6, the loss should be less than if the network predicted 5, because 6 is closer to the correct answer than 5. My understanding is that cross entropy and 1-hot vectors provides "all or nothing" loss rather than a "continuous" loss that reflects the magnitude of the error. If that is correct, how does one implement such a continuous loss in Tensorflow?

-- Update June 13 2016 ----

An example application might be color recognition. If the network predicts "green" but the true color is yellow-green, then the loss should be less than if the network predicted blue because green is a better prediction than blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to implement a continuous function (e.g. hue from HSV) as a single output, and construct your own loss calculation that reflects what you want to optimize. In that case you'd just have a single output value that ranged between 0.0 and 1.0, and the loss would be evaluated based on the distance from the labeled value.